# DynamoDB: Deleting an item without using primary key

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm implementing DynamoDB in our project. We have to put large data strings into database so we are splitting data into small pieces and inserting multiple rows with only one attribute value changed - part of string. One column (range key) contains a number of part. Inserting and selecting data works perfectly fine for small and large strings. The problem is deleting an item. I read that when you want to delete an item you need to specify primary key for such item (hash key or hash key and range key - depends on table). But what if I want to delete items that have particular value for one of attributes? Do I need to scan (scan, not query) entire table and for each row run delete or batch delete? Or is there some another solution without using two queries? What I'm trying to do is to avoid scanning entire table. I think we will have about 100 - 1000 milions of rows in such table, so scanning will be very slow.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered using S3 to store your big strings ? http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#When_should_I_use_Amazon_DynamoDB_vs_Amazon_S3 You can still use DynamoDB to store the S3 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **no way to delete an arbitrary element** in DynamoDB. You indeed need to know the `hash_key` and the `range_key`.

If `query` does not fit your needs for this (ie. you even do not know the `hash_key`), then you're stuck.

The best would be to **re-thing your data modeling**. Build a **[custom index](http://blog.coredumped.org/2012/01/amazon-dynamodb.html)** or do '**lazy delete**'.

To achieve 'lazy delete', use a table as a queue of element to delete. Periodically, run an EMR on it to do all the delete in the batch in a single scan operation. It's really not the best solution but the only way I can think of to avoid re-modeling.

**TL;DR**: There is no real way but workarounds. I highly recommend that you re-model at least part of your data.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I ended up with combining RangeKey with PartNumber so I can delete an item using two values. It worked fine. But now I must delete an item when I know only RangeKey. Reading article you linked I thought about creating additional table where my RangeKey from first table will be HashKey, and RangeKey will contain HashKey from first one. So when I'm trying to delete an item knowing only RangeKey I need to query my additional table and retrieve all data with RangeKeys. Now I kno HashKey's and RangeKey for my previous table an can run delete query. Is this right solution?

Comment: Can you update you initial question with a use case for this or start a new question? An example would be greatly appreciated to help you!